# Single use only setup for a specific hardware

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, setup-deployment

I am a newbie and not familiar with the setup environments and stuck at some point. I am developing a very simple database application using visual studio 2010. I want to release a demo program and want the demo setup to be executed just one time for a specific computer hardware. For example when one user downloads the demo and installs the setup, the demo setup content, a simple configuration file embedded in the setup or "what so ever I do not know" should be changed, so that setup (when coppied to another computer) could not be used in other computer hardwares.

**The sollutions or design ideas for this specific problem should not include any online services checking that the user executes that install or not. All the problem should be solved locally if possible :) and be as generic as possible.**

> Any design ideas or a starting point
>   will be very appreciated.

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible of course.  Whatever breadcrumb you leave to record that the program was ran has to be left on the same machine.  Leaving any user with sufficient skills or good enough tools (like SysInternals' ProcMon) to find out where you dropped it and remove it again.  Assuming they care enough about making the effort.

The simple solution is to intentionally cripple your demo so that an important feature is missing that would make it useful.  Like File + Save.  Not just disabled, completely missing in the code as well so hacking the demo program doesn't work either.  Easy to do with an #if directive in your source code.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer. Just because I am curios I want to ask 2 questions. Please forgive me if they are silly. Is it possible to embed a configuration file as you said a breadcrump into the setup file? 2. If the first question's anwer is yes, is it possible to alter that embedded configuration file? I guess it is a silly question because when OS is executed the setup file, its content on the harddisk is locked by the process so alteration to that file is impossible. I am just trying my luck. Thanks.

Comment: You can embed resources in a EXE, sure.  Updating it is very difficult, you can't open the EXE file for writing while your program is running.  You rarely even have write access at all due to UAC.  You have a helluva time finding the proper place to write.  And it offers no protection at all, they'll simply re-copy the EXE.

Comment: Ok this give me  fair amount of starting points. Thank you very much for your attention.